# C# Calculate Excel Cells based on Coloring or matching Cell Value

Tags: c#, .net, excel, windows, visual-studio

[Excel Cells background colered image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5NfS.jpg)

I would like to count the yellow back colored cells that matches with the values passed in to method and for each five columns would like to put a counted value in the last empty cell.

For example: A53 to E53 three values matched and painted so want to put (3) in to F53 then G53 (3) to K53 in to L53 and M53 (2) in to R53

Here is the code painting background if the integer value matches with the cell value. However after this match I also want to count yellowed cells and put counted value in to last Cell after each 5 count done. Please also look image for excel view.

```
    private void ExcelFindCellValue(string[] number, string cnums, string mnumber, bool bmega)
    {
        string fc = "";
        string sc = "";
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        objexcel = new Excel.Application();
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        if (!bmega)
        {
            if (cnums == "1")
            { fc = "A3"; sc = "E202"; }
            if (cnums == "2")
            { fc = "H3"; sc = "L202"; }
            if (cnums == "3")
            { fc = "O3"; sc = "S202"; }
        }
        else if (bmega)
        {
            if (cnums == "1")
            { fc = "F3"; sc = "F202"; }
            if (cnums == "2")
            { fc = "M3"; sc = "M202"; }
            if (cnums == "3")
            { fc = "T3"; sc = "T202"; }
            number[0] = mnumber;
            number[1] = ""; number[2] = ""; number[3] = ""; number[4] = "";
        }
        objexcel.DisplayAlerts = false;
        xlWorkBook = objexcel.Workbooks.Open(filePath, 0, false, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", true, true, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkBook.CheckCompatibility = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
        {
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            Excel.Range currentFind = null;
            Excel.Range firstFind = null;

            Excel.Range exRange = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.get_Range(fc, sc);
            // You should specify all these parameters every time you call this method,
            // since they can be overridden in the user interface. 

            currentFind = exRange.Find(number[i], misValue,
            Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole,
            Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, true,
            misValue, misValue);

            while (currentFind != null)
            {
                // Keep track of the first range you find. 
                if (firstFind == null)
                {
                    firstFind = currentFind;
                }

                // If you didn't move to a new range, you are done.
                else if (currentFind.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1)
                      == firstFind.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1))
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (!bmega)
                {
                    currentFind.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                    currentFind.Font.Bold = true;

                    currentFind.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
                }
                else if (bmega)
                {
                    currentFind.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
                    currentFind.Font.Bold = true;

                    currentFind.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                }

                currentFind = exRange.FindNext(currentFind);
            }
            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);

        }
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@filePath, misValue,
            misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
            misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook = objexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        objexcel.Quit();
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any code? What have you attempted so far? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We're not here to write code for you, we're here to help you debug your code.

Comment: Same as above. Please be more explicit

Comment: Thank you for advise, I appreciate it. I added my example code.

Comment: If you need any further explanation please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem. Here is an ugly but working code does the job. Sure I will clean and improve this code later on. However problem solved!

```
    private void FantasyExcelCalculateCellValue(string[] number, string cnums, string filePath)
    {
        string fc = "";
        string sc = "";
        int ifounded = 0;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        objexcel = new Excel.Application();
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        if (cnums == "1")
        { fc = "A2"; sc = "F2"; }
        if (cnums == "2")
        { fc = "G2"; sc = "L2"; }
        if (cnums == "3")
        { fc = "M2"; sc = "R2"; }
        string sr1 = "";
        string fr1 = "";
        string ov1 = fc.Remove(0, 1);
        string sr2 = "";
        string fr2 = "";
        string ov2 = sc.Remove(0, 1);
        objexcel.DisplayAlerts = false;
        objexcel.AutoCorrect.AutoExpandListRange = false;
        xlWorkBook = objexcel.Workbooks.Open(filePath, 0, false, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", true, true, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkBook.CheckCompatibility = false;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Excel.Range exRange = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.get_Range(fc, sc);
        xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        // Put another loop i from 2 to 500 and for each i increase range like A2 + 1 (A3) F2 + 1 (F3)
        for (int i = 2; i < 502; i++)
        {
            sr1 = i.ToString();
            sr2 = i.ToString();
            fr1 = fc.Replace(ov1, sr1);
            fr2 = sc.Replace(ov2, sr2);
            exRange = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.get_Range(fr1, fr2);
            int mj = 0;
            ifounded = 0;

            for (int m = 0; m < number.Length; m++)
                {
                    Excel.Range currentFind = null;
                    Excel.Range firstFind = null;
                    // You should specify all these parameters every time you call this method,
                    // since they can be overridden in the user interface. 

                    currentFind = exRange.Find(number[m], misValue, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, true, misValue, misValue);
                    while (currentFind != null)
                    {
                        // Keep track of the first range you find. 
                        if (firstFind == null)
                        {
                            firstFind = currentFind;
                        }

                        // If you didn't move to a new range, you are done.
                        else if (currentFind.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1) == firstFind.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1))
                        {
                            break;
                        }


                    int p = 0;
                    if (cnums == "1")
                    {
                        p = 6;
                    }
                    if (cnums == "2")
                    {
                        p = 12;
                    }
                    if (cnums == "3")
                    {
                        p = 18;
                    }
                    string icolor = currentFind.Interior.Color.ToString();
                    if (icolor == "65535")
                    {
                        ifounded++;
                        if (ifounded > 3)
                        {
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, p] = ifounded.ToString();
                            Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range(fr2, fr2) as Excel.Range;
                            range.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
                            range.Font.Bold = true;
                            range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                        }
                    }
                    currentFind = exRange.FindNext(currentFind);
                    }
                    mj++;
            }
        }
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@filePath, misValue,
            misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
            misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook = objexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        objexcel.Quit();
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
    }
```